# Is it a fact that vacuum energy exists?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I have always read that vacuum energy and zero point energy are established facts of physics supported by various observations of their effects both indirectly and even directly. But I have also read some comments from various physics discussion sites where they say that it is not a fact that vacuum energy exists, that it does not have conclusive evidence of its existence and that its effects can be ignored or replaced by other explanations in the theories that they contribute to.

So, is a fact that vacuum energy exists? Has it been ever proven to exist experimentally? If it has been, does the energy remain constant as space expands? Does that violate the law of energy conservation?

Answer (score 0):

> So, is a fact that vacuum energy exists?

Knowledge in science is always provisional, so we never know a fact with 100% certainty. However...

> Has it been ever proven to exist experimentally?

The cosmological constant (also known as vacuum energy) is a component of the standard $\Lambda$CDM cosmological model. It is currently the best scientific explanation for the observation that the Universe's expansion rate is accelerating, based on (among other things) the luminosity distance vs redshift relation for Type Ia supernova, combining information from the cosmic microwave background and large scale structure, and looking at the evolution of galaxy clusters properties over time. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe#Evidence_for_acceleration) has more information on these tests and links to additional references.

That's not to say that a cosmological constant is the *only* possible explanation of the accelerated rate of expansion. Other ideas include a new dynamical field acting as "dark energy" or a modification of GR on large scales. However, the cosmological constant is the simplest explanation and accounts for all observations to date.

> If it has been, does the energy remain constant as space expands?

The energy *density* remains constant as space expands.

> Does that violate the law of energy conservation?

Energy is not conserved in General Relativity except in special situations where the spacetime is *static* (see [1, 2, 3] and references therein for some discussion about this).

In cosmology, because the geometry is changing in time, there is no way to define a conserved energy.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy#Relativity

[2] https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html

[3] https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/