# Is the vacuum of space truly empty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle states that we cannot know the position and momentum of a particle with 100% certainty.
Does it apply to the vacuum of space?
If so, does this mean that a vacuum in space isn't truly ever empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a fact that vacuum energy exists?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/701789/is-it-a-fact-that-vacuum-energy-exists)

Comment: Maybe read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy

Comment: @rghome Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how one defines *vacuum*. E.g., if by *vacuum* we mean the outer space, then we cannot claim that it is completely empty. Although one could go here into a long discussion of whether particles are truly extended or how far they are extended.

If by *vacuum* we mean a concept of space with no particles (or other kind of matter, like waves) in it, then we nothing prevents us from using this concept, but, like many abstract concepts in physics, it is never literally realized.

Then in engineering one would often use *vacuum* in a specific sense of no atoms or molecules (often only with precision up to some concentration). This is the use we often encounter when we speak of *vacuum pumps* or *vacuum bulb* or *vacuum tube* in old TV monitors. This does exist, because it is by definition is non-ideal.

Finally, in quantum theories one often uses term *vacuum* as equivalent of a *ground state* - a state with no excitations in it. In many cases it actually means *unperturbed ground state*, which changes once we account for the interactions between the particles. It is in this sense that *vacuum* or *empty space* is referred to as a *boiling soup of virtual particles*.

Comment: UmU..thanks for the info!

Comment: Shouldn't one add that bodies in empty space are nevertheless subject to influences? After all, it follows the gravitational curvature of space. It warms up on the sunny side and is subject to EM radiation. If you leave all this out and only consider an isolated body without any surrounding influences, this consideration no longer makes any sense at all. There is no gain in knowledge.